# Extend a DataTable using a helper method to convert a database response to a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, static-methods

I have a public Manager class that uses a repository to make calls to my database and return the data as a DataTable. Once the data is returned as a DataTable, I then pass the DataTable to another function that returns a list of my custom object. The code is as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<ContractResponseModel> GetContracts(DateTime startDate)
        => ManagerExecute(() => ConvertDataTableToEntity(_contractRepository.RetrieveContracts(startDate)));
```

I think it will be cleaner to use a static method and have the call look something like as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<ContractResponseModel> GetContracts(DateTime startDate)
        => ManagerExecute(() => 
            _contractRepository
            .RetrieveContracts(startDate)
            .ToContractResponseModel())
           );
```

The current `ConvertDataTableToEntity` is as follows:

```
protected List<ContractResponseModel> ConvertDataTableToEntity(DataTable dt) =>
    dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new ContractResponseModel
    {
        SaleNo = row.Field<string>("SaleNo"),
        SaleDate = row.Field<DateTime>("SaleDate"),
        AvgFixPrice = row.Field<decimal>("AvgFixPrice")
    }).ToList();
```

I've tried variations of the following code, but cannot seem to get the DataTable passed to the static method.

```
public static IEnumerable<ContractResponseModel> ToContractResponseModel(this DataTable dt) =>
    dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new ContractResponseModel
    {
        SaleNo = row.Field<string>("SaleNo"),
        SaleDate = row.Field<DateTime>("SaleDate"),
        AvgFixPrice = row.Field<decimal>("AvgFixPrice")
    }).ToList();
```

Any fix for this code?